# How can my Flex application know when data is stale?

Tags: java, apache-flex, web-applications, blazeds, amf

I have a 100% Flex based enterprise web application with a Java/BlazeDS backend.  In order to create a more snappy user experience I'd like to load a bunch of data into the client right after logging in and hold it the entire session.

This would include items such as user preferences, application skins, application layouts, etc.  Things that are infrequently updated on the server.

My question is, in case they are updated, what's a good approach for refreshing the client side data...and knowing when to refresh?  I should say that I have no interest in Adobe LCDS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update data cached in the client, when that data changes on the server, you'll need to use a server side software that supports server push and will tell the client that an update is needed.

LiveCycle is one server side software that supports this.  I suspect you already knew that, since you call it out in your question.

GraniteDS is another, and since it is FOSS it may be more to your liking.

I suspect WebORB also supports push functionality, but don't hold me to that.

If you don't want to do anything server side; you could set up a call from the client to the server on some timer.

Comment: Does BlazeDS support server push?

Comment: @HDave No, it doesn't.  For that, Adobe wants you to go to use LiveCycle.  I can respect the Adobe stance that "Server Push" is only needed in Enterprise class apps and Enterprises will benefit from purchasing some kind of premium support contract.

Comment: Found a great article on this subject that confirms BlazeDS does not have server push.  It can simulate it however via long polling, but it eats up threads on the server machine.  Check it out:  http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2008/5/21/The-Truth-About-BlazeDS-and-Push-Messaging

Comment: Even if you use LCDS you can go into firewall/proxies issues if you intend to use the "true" push method. Do you really have such a large number of concurrent users and do you really have the need for near real time notifications? If not BlazeDS should be fine. Btw GraniteDS is using the same mechanism as BlazeDS. On the other hand WebORB supports RTMP protocol.

Comment: At this time, I honestly do not have such a need, but am always thinking about the future....and one thread per connected user can't possibly scale beyond a few dozen users no?  Also...check out this article...apparently these guys have an open-source solution to NIO server push:  http://flex.sys-con.com/node/720304

Comment: I would say at least several hundreds..you can increase the number of threads from your app server and you can do some fine tuning (like setting up the maximum thread stack trace). Yes, the Farata guys are doing a great job. In future I expect to have reliable NIO containers for most of the app servers. (I know that some of them have them right now, but I've seen some internal tests where they crashed). I'm suggesting BlazeDS over another open source product because of the product maturity - when you have issues related to messaging is really painful to debug/investigate.

Answer (score -1):

Well by nature Flex is pretty much one-way and you can only get data into Flex by using an HTTPRequest - you can't just send data to a Flex client (at least not using Apache). Your best bet is to store a timestamp of preference data locally in the Flex app and use an httprequest to look up if the timestamp locally still matches the timestamp of the data in your backend app at a regular interval (ie every five minutes).

Comment: -1 for having a inaccurate answer.  It is true you can't do server side push with "just Apache."  But, it is nottrue that Flex, by nature, is one way.  Flex (The Flash Player) supports sockets, which can be used to leave a connection open with the server which can be used for the server to send information to the client.  But, you need a server side program to do so (like LiveCycle).

Comment: Yes, but without LiveCycle it is effectively one way. And the OP SPECIFICALLY said he has absolutely no interest in LiveCycle. So without the benefit of as server push to the flash player, what would be the best solution?

Comment: @Jack "Without LifeCycle it is effectively one way."  That's not true.  There are other options, as stated in my answer.  WebORB and GraniteDS both claim to offer server push functionality.  In theory, one could write their own server side software to support server side push.  I did read the question, and addressed the OP distate for livecycle in my answer.  I'm sorry you felt the need to down vote me in retaliation.

Comment: Little difference between "-1" in a comment and "-1" vote down on a valid answer. You clearly have the rep to have changed my answer to redact that part if you really wanted.

Comment: @Jack I already posted my own answer to your question, which others have agreed with including the original post.  Yes, I could have edited your question, however once we remove the inaccuracies of your answer and the points I consider to be bad advice, there wouldn't be anything left.

Comment: You said: 'If you don't want to do anything server side; you could set up a call from the client to the server on some timer.'... I had the same answer as you.